# Instrumentation and publishing application

Tags: android

I'd like to use Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor to know if some activity is created. But the ["The AndroidManifest.xml File"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) article says I must remove `<instrumentation>` from AndroidManifest.xml before publishing app. Why should I do it and why I can't use Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor in published app?

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure, but probably `<instrumentation>` is not needed in AndroidManifest.xml in order to use Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor?